# GridView.builder creates page that scrolls endlessly

Tags: dart, flutter

Trying to use an API to build the grid. Everything renders fine but after the last row of tiles the page goes blank & just keeps scrolling & scrolling &... the grid is built like so:

```
body: new GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: (orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 2 : 3),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Card(
          child: new GridTile(
            footer: new Text(data[index]['name']),
              child: new Text(data[index]['image']), //just for testing, will fill with image later
          ),
        );
      },
  )
```

The exception as I continually scroll further down the blank page with the last number (inclusive: 24) getting larger by multiples of 2 (24,26,28,etc).

```
I/flutter (11001): Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..23, inclusive: 24
```

Anyone seen this behavior with GridView.builder?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can pass the item count to the builder.

Example:

```
body: GridView.builder(
  itemCount: data.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: (orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 2 : 3),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new Card(
      child: new GridTile(
        footer: new Text(data[index]['name']),
        child: new Text(data[index]
            ['image']), //just for testing, will fill with image later
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Where `final orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;`

Hope that helped!

Comment: How to give portrait and landscape orientation in gridview builder.i want to give both orientation for my gridview

Comment: Actually, wrap the `Gridview` inside a `OrientationBuilder`, which gives the current orientation.

Comment: how can I set the fixed height of the container inside the gridView.build not depending on childAspectRatio?

Comment: For orientation, use this                                                                                 ````crossAxisCount:
                (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape)
                    ? 4
                    : 1,````